# Unable to make relation in has-one-through

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, has-one-through

I'm trying to make an relationship in has-one-through.

Tables:

```
packages
    -guest_detail_id

guest_details
    -client_id

clients
    -id
```

in Package.php

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Packages extends Model {
  /**
   * Get the client.
   */
  public function client() {
      return $this->hasOneThrough(---what will be params---);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are basically looking for a `BelongsToThrough` relationship, so you have to swap the foreign and local keys:

```
public function client() {
    return $this->hasOneThrough(
        Client::class, GuestDetails::class,
        'id', 'id',
        'guest_detail_id', 'client_id'
    );
}
```

Comment: you are right, I am actually looking for `BelongsToThrough` method and `hasOneThrough` method added in laravel 5.8 so i got confused how to do that.

Comment: Laravel has no native `BelongsToThrough` relationship, but there is a package for that (I'm the maintainer): https://github.com/staudenmeir/belongs-to-through

Answer (score 1):

In your question, I found that one package has one client. which cannot implement through a direct relation. 
this could be done through `hasOneThrough()` relation ship.

`hasOneThrough()` relation can be achieved through a intermediate table, here your`guest_details`. so the relation becomes `One package has one GuestDetails and one GuestDetails has one client, hence one package has one Client`.

```
 public function client() {
    return $this->hasOneThrough(Client::class, GuestDetails::class, 'client_id', 'id');
 }
```

Comment: Could you please add some bits of information so OP can understand? Thank you.